# Is there a kind of ORDBMS where I can create classes on the fly?

Tags: java, database, objectdb, ordbms

It is a bit hard to explain, what I am looking for:

Searching for a DB which stores objects (similar to e.g. https://www.objectdb.com/) but where classes are not defined by the Java code but in the DB itself - on the fly.

So that there it shall be possible e.g. to create a class maybe with a rest call:

```
{
 action: create_class,
 type: Car,
 properties: {
  color: String,
  producer: String,
  price: Integer,
 }
}
```

And add an item like:

```
{
 action: create_entry,
 class: Car,
 id: 123456,
 {
  color: red,
  price: 20000,
  producter: Hypercar
 } 
}
```

Before you now say: "NOSQL!": There it seems to be the issue with relations and queries. E.g. "find all red cars" or "find cars of a producer with criteria XY"

But maybe there exists a DB solution which provides already a lot of functions - a mixture between SQL and NOSQL?

For example the product [fibery](https://fibery.io/) provides a way to add kind of entities per mouse. That is very inspiring. (Fibery is not a DB but a product doing what I am looking for)

Answer (score 1):

You may look at https://www.prisma.io/
It supports sql-like databases as backend (Postgresql etc) and provides REST and GraphQL based query languages.

> Prisma works fundamentally different compared to that. With Prisma, you define your models in the declarative Prisma schema which serves as the single source of truth for your database schema and the models in your programming language. In your application code, you can then use Prisma Client to read and write data in your database in a type-safe manner without the overhead of managing complex model instances. This makes the process of querying data a lot more natural as well as more predictable since Prisma Client always returns plain JavaScript objects.

also here is a glimpse of relation queries https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries

As a developer of Fibery, I should say that it isn't optimised for general use like Postgresql or any other true database in the field.

Comment: Thanks Victor, that is very interesting!